# How to use SimplePagination jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-pagination

I am trying to use [simplePagination](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/#page-65) on my code. (I am developing using MVC4 C#)

Let say I have this bunch of codes

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" /></td>
            <td style="text-align: left">Name</td>
            <td style="text-align: left">Created By</td>
            <td style="text-align: left">Created Date</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="post">
            <td><p><input Length="0" name="314" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="314" type="hidden" value="false" /></p></td>
            <td>Window</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>01/01/2014 12:00:00 AM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="post">
            <td><p><input Length="0" name="314" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="314" type="hidden" value="false" /></p></td>
            <td>Door</td>
            <td>Chris</td>
            <td>01/01/2014 12:00:00 AM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="post">
            <td><p><input Length="0" name="314" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="314" type="hidden" value="false" /></p></td>
            <td>Floor</td>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>01/01/2014 12:00:00 AM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="post">
            <td><p><input Length="0" name="314" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="314" type="hidden" value="false" /></p></td>
            <td>Car</td>
            <td>James</td>
            <td>01/01/2014 12:00:00 AM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="post">
            <td><p><input Length="0" name="314" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="314" type="hidden" value="false" /></p></td>
            <td>Bike</td>
            <td>Steven</td>
            <td>01/01/2014 12:00:00 AM</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*Note: In the code above I add class 'post' to each 'tr' (row in table body). And these rows are generated dynamically by for loop (C#)

And from the documentation if I want to use [simplePagination](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/#page-65) I have to declare the jquery like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(selector).pagination({
        items: 100,
        itemsOnPage: 10,
        cssStyle: 'light-theme'
    });
});
```

Actually I am not pretty sure how to use (*how to call) this [simplePagination](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/#page-65). It's my first time dealing with pagination.

I already tried to put this code after the table

```
<div class="pagination-page"></div>
```

And change 'Selector' inside jquery calling method with '.pagination-page', but it didn't work.

```
$(function() {
    $('.pagination-page').pagination({
        items: 100,
        itemsOnPage: 10,
        cssStyle: 'light-theme'
    });
});
```

1. Should I replace 'Selector' with a class name? If yes, how do I do that?
2. Second is how do I declare this [simplePagination](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/#page-65) so that it will show only 2 rows (Only 2 class 'Post') for each page?

*Means in the first page it will only show

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
| [] |  Name  | CreatedBy | CreatedDate            | 
|--------------------------------------------------| 
| [] | Window | John      | 01/01/2014 12:00:00 AM | 
| [] | Door   | Chris     | 01/01/2014 12:00:00 AM | 
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

The second page will show

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
| [] |  Name  | CreatedBy | CreatedDate            | 
|--------------------------------------------------| 
| [] | Floor  | Michael   | 01/01/2014 12:00:00 AM | 
| [] | Car    | James     | 01/01/2014 12:00:00 AM | 
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

So on..

*Note: I am not sure how this jquery will detect how many items we have and generate number of pages and put those items accordingly.

Comment: Is that pagination code you're using showing anything at all? If you did all the links according to step 1 and 2 in the simplePagination links you included then with that code you should see a "light-theme"d page navigator with 10 pages that, when clicked, do nothing :P If you're seeing that then I can proceed to helping you actually get the pagination working with your table :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

One thing to note about this plugin, which a few people may get confused about, is that it technically doesn’t implement pagination itself. It generates a page navigator and provides the means, via jQuery events, to simply hook it up to our own pagination functionality.

Assuming you've followed the steps 1 (and 2 if you want the CSS styling) required from the [simplePagination](https://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/) link you included in your question then the following jQuery will do what you need:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Consider adding an ID to your table
    // incase a second table ever enters the picture.
    var items = $("table tbody tr");

    var numItems = items.length;
    var perPage = 2;

    // Only show the first 2 (or first `per_page`) items initially.
    items.slice(perPage).hide();

    // Now setup the pagination using the `.pagination-page` div.
    $(".pagination-page").pagination({
        items: numItems,
        itemsOnPage: perPage,
        cssStyle: "light-theme",

        // This is the actual page changing functionality.
        onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
            // We need to show and hide `tr`s appropriately.
            var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
            var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

            // We'll first hide everything...
            items.hide()
                 // ... and then only show the appropriate rows.
                 .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
        }
    });



    // EDIT: Let's cover URL fragments (i.e. #page-3 in the URL).
    // More thoroughly explained (including the regular expression) in: 
    // https://github.com/bilalakil/bin/tree/master/simplepagination/page-fragment/index.html

    // We'll create a function to check the URL fragment
    // and trigger a change of page accordingly.
    function checkFragment() {
        // If there's no hash, treat it like page 1.
        var hash = window.location.hash || "#page-1";

        // We'll use a regular expression to check the hash string.
        hash = hash.match(/^#page-(\d+)$/);

        if(hash) {
            // The `selectPage` function is described in the documentation.
            // We've captured the page number in a regex group: `(\d+)`.
            $(".pagination-page").pagination("selectPage", parseInt(hash[1]));
        }
    };

    // We'll call this function whenever back/forward is pressed...
    $(window).bind("popstate", checkFragment);

    // ... and we'll also call it when the page has loaded
    // (which is right now).
    checkFragment();



});
```

You can find a running example [here](https://bilalakil.github.io/bin/simplepagination/), and a more thorough guide on simplePagination [here](https://bilalakil.me/simplepagination) if you want to more thoroughly understand how this all actually works.

**EDIT:** Added a section of code to handle URL fragments (on reload and on back/forward) as Mike O'Connor highlighted the need for. You can see a live example of URL fragment handling [here](https://bilalakil.github.io/bin/simplepagination/page-fragment/#page-2).

**EDIT 2:** If you need cross-browser compatibility for the back/forward fragment updating (i.e. IE11...), include the [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) script before implementing the above code. Thanks to Mike O'Connor for that :)

**EDIT 3:** If you're dynamically adding or removing content you'll need to manually update the paginator to reflect these changes. I've whipped up an example for that too. You can see it running [here](https://bilalakil.github.io/bin/simplepagination/dynamic-content/).

Comment: I would suggest to use jquery slice method [Ref: http://api.jquery.com/slice/] for filtering task instead of items.each loop. e.g. $("table tr").slice(start, start + per_page).show();

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! It's working :) So we have to append our own code to hide and show some items. I thought it's all already handled by the simplePagination jquery. Thanks a lot man :D

Comment: PS: I did a full walkthrough on using simplePagination here: http://bilalakil.me/simplepagination/

Comment: Would SimplePagination also work for items that are not in the table?

http://www.ctv.ca/MasterChefCanada/video.aspx

For example, i want to paginate all the video clips using SimplePagination on this site, would that be possible?

Comment: It doesn't need to use a table, it can use whatever you want - you just need to adapt the JavaScript/jQuery - i.e. you'll need to show/hide batches of 9 videos at a time instead of 9 table rows at a time.

Comment: Bilal I have edited my answer to show that you've dealt with the prior limitations. Thanks much again.

Comment: @BilalAkil Sir i want to paginate a table that is yet to be populate what should i do about it?i am following your sample about but i cant figure out what to do inorder to achieve what i want

Comment: @HogRider, it is your duty to provide the HTML that you wish to apply pagination to. You need to provide the table yourself, just as you would've needed to if you weren't using any form of pagination. Once you've got the table sorted out you can try to follow the above example and apply it to your specific case.

Comment: @BilalAkil yes sir i am able to put data to table after ajax success. i added the classname to each row but it didnt paginate those row it is still showing all. I am expecting that 2 rows will only appear because it is stated in the `main.js` the buttons are not even clickable so something is wrong

Comment: @HogRider, if you're dynamically adding or removing items which you want to paginate then it's more complicated.. I'll update the answer with more information for you. Please give me a moment :)

Comment: @BilalAkil yes i am updating that table dynamically because the data i put into that table is from select statement returned from ajax success i will wait for the update

Comment: @BilalAkil there are only a few questions i dont get from the upated answer how to set the number of items?i changed the `perPage` but the number of items does not change.also i am doing this in table so items = `$("#content tbody tr");` what to change this in a way that the header wont disappear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78267/discussion-between-bilal-akil-and-hogrider).

Comment: @BilalAkil Thanks alot man, genius, clean, neat, awesome, you really life saver

Comment: @BilalAkil Infinite thanks for the simple and neat solution. As Melvin said, you're a life saver! But may i know if i'm able to apply this pagination to a table that is loading the data using AJAX?

Comment: @Nurul, appreciate your compliments :) Regarding AJAX, check the link in edit 3 regarding how to deal with dynamic data. You'll basically want to update the pagination each time the data is updated. Consider contacting me by some other means (not in this comment thread) if you have more questions.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I've tested Bilal Akil's jQuery(function($) and it was a good start for me--- thanks Bilal. It works, but with some deficiencies. For one, if you go to [his first link](http://bilalakil.github.io/bin/simplepagination/) and click on a page 2 then that number appears in the location box as "http://bilalakil.github.io/bin/simplepagination/#page-2"--- in the #page-2. But if you copy that entire URL and paste it into the location box of another tab or window to simulate someone linking to page 2, then it flat doesn't work; you'll find yourself on page 1. Or after you click on the page 2 button and go to page 2 you can just reload the page; you'll find yourself on page 1.

I would have commented but I need to leave some code here. Here's my modified jQuery(function($) with the fix of that particular problem:

```
  var items = $("#content .page");
  var numItems = items.length;
  var hashPageNum = getPageNum();  //code for getPageNum() is below
  items.hide().slice(hashPageNum-1, hashPageNum).show();

  // now setup pagination
  $("#pagination").pagination({

    items: numItems,
    itemsOnPage: 1,
    cssStyle: "light-theme",
    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
    items.hide().slice(pageNumber-1, pageNumber).show();
    }

  });
  $('#pagination').pagination('drawPage', hashPageNum);
```

I should have prefaced this by saying that the selector scheme that I'm using for the page elements is as follows:

```
<div id="pagination"></div>
<table id="content"><tbody><tr class="page"><td>...
```

And I'm using just perPage=1, one <tr> per page, but the essential difference is this line:

```
items.hide().slice(hashPageNum-1, hashPageNum).show();
```

It is the main fix for that problem about links with the #page-n on the end not working. The last line is also necessary for that purpose as it sets the pagination bar with page n shown selected.

The second problem is the utter dysfunction of the back and forward buttons with Bilal's bare code. If you put the pagination bar at the bottom of a long page readers are surely going to want to use the browser's built-in page navigation. **EDIT:** Bilal has since updated his code to remove these problems.

So here's a function that has an essential detail toward that end. It's called in the code above but in one other place too:

```
function getPageNum(){
  var hashtag = parent.location.hash;
  var hashPageNum = 1; //default
  if (hashtag == '#page-1') {
    hashPageNum=1;
  } else if (hashtag == '#page-2'){
    hashPageNum=2;
  } else if (hashtag == '#page-3') {
    hashPageNum=3;
  } else if (hashtag == '') {
    hashPageNum=1;
    parent.location.hash = '#page-1';
  };
  return hashPageNum;
};
```

OK, I comprehend that I have not been sophisticated, but the essential detail is that if parent.location.hash is null then the function returns 1, for page 1--- not null.

There is now one other step, and that's to weaponize window.onpopstate, which is an HTML5 thing (hopefully this won't cause a problem with non-html5 browsers... comment if you know all about that please):

```
window.onpopstate = function(e){
  var pagenum = getPageNum();
  $("#content .page").hide().slice(pagenum-1, pagenum).show();
  $('#pagination').pagination('drawPage', pagenum);
};
```

And with that I appear to be done. I can copy the URL's with the #page-n suffixes and launch them elsewhere and they work. The forward and back buttons work. Note that the 'drawPage" bit in the code immediately above is simply to adjust the indication in the pagination bar.

OK, this is an edit on 2/16/2015... to show a fix for the IE11 problem which is discussed in the comments. I didn't edit the code above because perhaps you won't want to do the fix this way, though it does seem to work.

First go to [this github project](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API) and then type "t" for files (hah!) and click on history.min.js and then on the Raw button and do a SaveAs in your browser. So you'll be using that JavaScript library which effectively creates popstate events (and other events) for browsers that don't raise them.

Now, in the code above delete the window.onpopstate = function(e){} but save its code block and insert it at the end of the jQuery(function($), right after $('#pagination').pagination('drawPage', hashPageNum);, as follows:

```
  $(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
  var pagenum = getPageNum();
   $("#content .page").hide().slice(pagenum-1, pagenum).show();
   $('#pagination').pagination('drawPage', pagenum);
  });
```

EDIT I have to add that if you put a link to one of your thus-paginated pages on your site--- e.g., your home page probably has anchors in the menu that go to some of your paginated pages--- then if you put target="_blank" in the link and for the href put www.yourdomain.com/yourpaginatedpage, everything will be fine. It will be fine because you won't be trying to use the back arrow on your browser to get back to your home page as the paginated page will be opening as a new tab or new window.

But... if you leave off the target="_blank" and so open the paginated page in the same window you will find that the back button doesn't work. The history is there to see when you press on the back arrow (actually it's wrong since there are *two* listings of yourpaginatedpage) but no amount of clicking on the arrow will cause it to work.

The cure is simply to put www.yourdomain.com/yourpaginatedpage#page-1 in as your href... with the #page-1. Then the back arrow will work.

Comment: @Bilal Akil, thanks much for the kind words... appreciated here. Your code was the only thing that I could find that made sense and so I went with it. Now for the bad news: the Back and Forward arrows still don't work on IE11. The other improvements do however, and it's not as though the arrows do something goofy on IE11; they simply do nothing. I found a site that ranks browsers by HTML5 support and of the top five IE11 ranks last.

Comment: Nicely done again. It's a shame that we still need polyfills for the newest version of IE :/ but that's just life isn't it :P Check out the edit to my answer for a neat incorporation of page fragment handling! It might look hefty but it's mostly comments.

Answer (score 1):

Following code work for me :

```
function paginationTable() {

    var items = $("table tbody tr");
    var tablaeBody = $("table tbody");
        var numItems = items.length;
        var perPage = 20;

        // Only show the first 20 (or first `per_page`) items initially.
        tablaeBody.html(items.slice(0,20));
        // Now setup the pagination using the `.pagination-page` div.
        $(".pagination-page").pagination({
            items: numItems,
            itemsOnPage: perPage,
            cssStyle: "light-theme",

            // This is the actual page changing functionality.
            onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
                // We need to show and hide `tr`s appropriately.
                var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
                var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

                tablaeBody.html(items.slice(showFrom,showTo));

            }
        });
}
```

call this function after prepare your HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the Bilal Akil's jQuery(function($)) and I found one mistake that I would like to correct - And thanks Bilal for your involvement on this topic.

As I cannot post a comment or suggest an edit of his post, I will post my answer directly here. For further information look at the Bilal Akil's post.

The selector for pagination was wrong (not the same in fact) in the code as I tried it on a website so I decided to edit your post and by the way I added 2 variables to ensure flexibility for future changes or own customization.

```
// mind the slight change below, personal idea of best practices
jQuery(function($) {
    // consider adding an id to your table,
    // just incase a second table ever enters the picture..?
    var items = $("table tbody tr");

    var numItems = items.length;
    var perPage = 2;

    var pagination_placeholder_selector = ".pagination-page"; // put in a variable to ensure proper changes in the future
    var myPageName = "#page-"; // a number will follow for each page

    // only show the first 2 (or "first per_page") items initially
    items.slice(perPage).hide();

    // now setup your pagination
    // you need that .pagination-page div before/after your table
    $(pagination_placeholder_selector).pagination({
        items: numItems,
        itemsOnPage: perPage,
        cssStyle: "light-theme",
        hrefTextPrefix: myPageName,
        onPageClick: function(pageNumber) { // this is where the magic happens
            // someone changed page, lets hide/show trs appropriately
            var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
            var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

            items.hide() // first hide everything, then show for the new page
                 .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
        }
    });



    // EDIT: extra stuff to cover url fragments (i.e. #page-3)
    // https://github.com/bilalakil/bin/tree/master/simplepagination/page-fragment
    // is more thoroughly commented (to explain the regular expression)

    // we'll create a function to check the url fragment and change page
    // we're storing this function in a variable so we can reuse it
    var checkFragment = function() {
        // if there's no hash, make sure we go to page 1
        var hash = window.location.hash || (myPageName+"1");

        // we'll use regex to check the hash string
        var re = new RegExp("^"+myPageName+"(\\d+)$");
        hash = hash.match(re);

        if(hash)
            // the selectPage function is described in the documentation
            // we've captured the page number in a regex group: (\d+)
            $(pagination_placeholder_selector).pagination("selectPage", parseInt(hash[1]));
    };

    // we'll call this function whenever the back/forward is pressed
    $(window).bind("popstate", checkFragment);

    // and we'll also call it to check right now!
    checkFragment();



});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have converted Bilal Akil's work into a function and called it into ajax as I am loading data by ajax call. It works awesome. Thanks to all participants.

```
function paginate() {
// consider adding an id to your table,
// just incase a second table ever enters the picture..?
var items = jQuery("#searched_prfiles .row .col-md-4");

var numItems = items.length;
var perPage = 2;

var pagination_placeholder_selector = "#pagination_links"; // put in a variable to ensure proper changes in the future
var myPageName = "#page-"; // a number will follow for each page

// only show the first 2 (or "first per_page") items initially
items.slice(perPage).hide();

// now setup your pagination
// you need that .pagination-page div before/after your table
jQuery(pagination_placeholder_selector).pagination({
    items: numItems,
    itemsOnPage: perPage,
    cssStyle: "light-theme",
    hrefTextPrefix: myPageName,
    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) { // this is where the magic happens
        // someone changed page, lets hide/show trs appropriately
        var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
        var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

        items.hide() // first hide everything, then show for the new page
             .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
    }
});



// EDIT: extra stuff to cover url fragments (i.e. #page-3)
// https://github.com/bilalakil/bin/tree/master/simplepagination/page-fragment
// is more thoroughly commented (to explain the regular expression)

// we'll create a function to check the url fragment and change page
// we're storing this function in a variable so we can reuse it
var checkFragment = function() {
    // if there's no hash, make sure we go to page 1
    var hash = window.location.hash || (myPageName+"1");

    // we'll use regex to check the hash string
    var re = new RegExp("^"+myPageName+"(\\d+)$");
    hash = hash.match(re);

    if(hash)
        // the selectPage function is described in the documentation
        // we've captured the page number in a regex group: (\d+)
        jQuery(pagination_placeholder_selector).pagination("selectPage", parseInt(hash[1]));
};

// we'll call this function whenever the back/forward is pressed
jQuery(window).bind("popstate", checkFragment);

// and we'll also call it to check right now!
checkFragment();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mio_path_js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mio_path_js/jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mio_path_css/simplePagination.css"/>
```

And after,for 10 elements call Ajax function as:

```
$(function() {
  $(#id_paginator").pagination({
    items: 100,
    itemsOnPage: 10,
    cssStyle: 'light-theme'
  });
});
```

Or if you want to load all element:

$.ajax({
    ......
    ......
    success: function (response, status, xhr) {
        jQuery(function($) {
        var pageParts = $(".paginate");
        var numPages = countSelect;
        var perPage = 10;
        pageParts.slice(perPage).hide();

```
        $("#page-nav").pagination({
        items: numPages,
        itemsOnPage: perPage,
        cssStyle: "light-theme",
        currentPage: numeroSelezionato,
            onPageClick: function(pageNum) {
                $("#myModalWaiting").show();
                var start = perPage * (pageNum - 1);
                var end = start + perPage;
                cambiaPagina(start,end,pageNum);
                numeroSelezionato = pageNum;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

)};

The Html code is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <td>
                ............
                ...............
                .................
            </td>
        </th>
     </tr></table>
<div id="id_paginator"></div>
```

[image]

For other Jquery simplePagination example see [here](https://lentux-informatica.com/paginazione-liste-con-jquery-parte1-2-simplepagination-js/).

Or for more element to load: 
https://lentux-informatica.com/paginazione-liste-con-jquery-parte-2-2-simplepagination-js/