# JQuery simplePagination.js Browser History

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, pagination

I recently integrated JQuery's simplePagination.js into my html and am happy.  Everything is working.... Except for the browser history part of it.  When clicking on a page number in the pagination, I can see the browser's url bar changing in accordance to keep track of what page the user is on. Unfortunately, I noted that when clicking "Back" on the browser, the url does change back to the previous page, but the website's content and pagination number that is selected does not change back. i.e.  1 2 3 4 5 Next is the pagination buttons...  If I click them in order, and am currently on 4.  If I click "Back" on the browser, the button highlighted is still 4 and so is the content relevant to 4.  It did not change back to 3.  The only thing that changed back to 3 was the url.

I originally got my code working (almost) with this stackoverflow posting >>> [How to use SimplePagination jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896076/how-to-use-simplepagination-jquery)

In that posting, user 2unco, suggested some code and then included an example of it working.

For convenience, I will include all code mentioned there for my example:

HTML content to be paginated:
(Unable to figure out how to post html code, without it being translated to actual content)
...Please see this post for HTML code example. [How to use SimplePagination jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896076/how-to-use-simplepagination-jquery)
Suggested javascript to add to the HTML:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // consider adding an id to your table,
    // just incase a second table ever enters the picture..?
    var items = $("table tbody tr");

    var numItems = items.length;
    var perPage = 2;

    // only show the first 2 (or "first per_page") items initially
    items.slice(perPage).hide();

    // now setup your pagination
    // you need that .pagination-page div before/after your table
    $(".pagination-page").pagination({
        items: numItems,
        itemsOnPage: perPage,
        cssStyle: "light-theme",
        onPageClick: function(pageNumber) { // this is where the magic happens
            // someone changed page, lets hide/show trs appropriately
            var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
            var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

            items.hide() // first hide everything, then show for the new page
                 .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
        }
    });
});
```

And simplePagination.js

```
(function($){

    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            var o = $.extend({
                items: 1,
                itemsOnPage: 1,
                pages: 0,
                displayedPages: 5,
                edges: 2,
                currentPage: 0,
                hrefTextPrefix: '#page-',
                hrefTextSuffix: '',
                prevText: 'Prev',
                nextText: 'Next',
                ellipseText: '&hellip;',
                cssStyle: 'light-theme',
                labelMap: [],
                selectOnClick: true,
                nextAtFront: false,
                invertPageOrder: false,
                onPageClick: function(pageNumber, event) {
                    // Callback triggered when a page is clicked
                    // Page number is given as an optional parameter
                },
                onInit: function() {
                    // Callback triggered immediately after initialization
                }
            }, options || {});

            var self = this;

            o.pages = o.pages ? o.pages : Math.ceil(o.items / o.itemsOnPage) ? Math.ceil(o.items / o.itemsOnPage) : 1;
            if (o.currentPage)
                o.currentPage = o.currentPage - 1;
            else
                o.currentPage = !o.invertPageOrder ? 0 : o.pages - 1;
            o.halfDisplayed = o.displayedPages / 2;

            this.each(function() {
                self.addClass(o.cssStyle + ' simple-pagination').data('pagination', o);
                methods._draw.call(self);
            });

            o.onInit();

            return this;
        },

        selectPage: function(page) {
            methods._selectPage.call(this, page - 1);
            return this;
        },

        prevPage: function() {
            var o = this.data('pagination');
            if (!o.invertPageOrder) {
                if (o.currentPage > 0) {
                    methods._selectPage.call(this, o.currentPage - 1);
                }
            } else {
                if (o.currentPage < o.pages - 1) {
                    methods._selectPage.call(this, o.currentPage + 1);
                }
            }
            return this;
        },

        nextPage: function() {
            var o = this.data('pagination');
            if (!o.invertPageOrder) {
                if (o.currentPage < o.pages - 1) {
                    methods._selectPage.call(this, o.currentPage + 1);
                }
            } else {
                if (o.currentPage > 0) {
                    methods._selectPage.call(this, o.currentPage - 1);
                }
            }
            return this;
        },

        getPagesCount: function() {
            return this.data('pagination').pages;
        },

        getCurrentPage: function () {
            return this.data('pagination').currentPage + 1;
        },

        destroy: function(){
            this.empty();
            return this;
        },

        drawPage: function (page) {
            var o = this.data('pagination');
            o.currentPage = page - 1;
            this.data('pagination', o);
            methods._draw.call(this);
            return this;
        },

        redraw: function(){
            methods._draw.call(this);
            return this;
        },

        disable: function(){
            var o = this.data('pagination');
            o.disabled = true;
            this.data('pagination', o);
            methods._draw.call(this);
            return this;
        },

        enable: function(){
            var o = this.data('pagination');
            o.disabled = false;
            this.data('pagination', o);
            methods._draw.call(this);
            return this;
        },

        updateItems: function (newItems) {
            var o = this.data('pagination');
            o.items = newItems;
            o.pages = methods._getPages(o);
            this.data('pagination', o);
            methods._draw.call(this);
        },

        updateItemsOnPage: function (itemsOnPage) {
            var o = this.data('pagination');
            o.itemsOnPage = itemsOnPage;
            o.pages = methods._getPages(o);
            this.data('pagination', o);
            methods._selectPage.call(this, 0);
            return this;
        },

        _draw: function() {
            var o = this.data('pagination'),
                interval = methods._getInterval(o),
                i,
                tagName;

            methods.destroy.call(this);

            tagName = (typeof this.prop === 'function') ? this.prop('tagName') : this.attr('tagName');

            var $panel = tagName === 'UL' ? this : $('<ul></ul>').appendTo(this);

            // Generate Prev link
            if (o.prevText) {
                methods._appendItem.call(this, !o.invertPageOrder ? o.currentPage - 1 : o.currentPage + 1, {text: o.prevText, classes: 'prev'});
            }

            // Generate Next link (if option set for at front)
            if (o.nextText && o.nextAtFront) {
                methods._appendItem.call(this, !o.invertPageOrder ? o.currentPage + 1 : o.currentPage - 1, {text: o.nextText, classes: 'next'});
            }

            // Generate start edges
            if (!o.invertPageOrder) {
                if (interval.start > 0 && o.edges > 0) {
                    var end = Math.min(o.edges, interval.start);
                    for (i = 0; i < end; i++) {
                        methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
                    }
                    if (o.edges < interval.start && (interval.start - o.edges != 1)) {
                        $panel.append('<li class="disabled"><span class="ellipse">' + o.ellipseText + '</span></li>');
                    } else if (interval.start - o.edges == 1) {
                        methods._appendItem.call(this, o.edges);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (interval.end < o.pages && o.edges > 0) {
                    var begin = Math.max(o.pages - o.edges, interval.end);
                    for (i = o.pages - 1; i >= begin; i--) {
                        methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
                    }
                    if (o.pages - o.edges > interval.end && (o.pages - o.edges - interval.end != 1)) {
                        $panel.append('<li class="disabled"><span class="ellipse">' + o.ellipseText + '</span></li>');
                    } else if (o.pages - o.edges - interval.end == 1) {
                        methods._appendItem.call(this, interval.end);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Generate interval links
            if (!o.invertPageOrder) {
                for (i = interval.start; i < interval.end; i++) {
                    methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
                }
            } else {
                for (i = interval.end - 1; i >= interval.start; i--) {
                    methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
                }
            }

            // Generate end edges
            if (!o.invertPageOrder) {
                if (interval.end < o.pages && o.edges > 0) {
                    if (o.pages - o.edges > interval.end && (o.pages - o.edges - interval.end != 1)) {
                        $panel.append('<li class="disabled"><span class="ellipse">' + o.ellipseText + '</span></li>');
                    } else if (o.pages - o.edges - interval.end == 1) {
                        methods._appendItem.call(this, interval.end);
                    }
                    var begin = Math.max(o.pages - o.edges, interval.end);
                    for (i = begin; i < o.pages; i++) {
                        methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (interval.start > 0 && o.edges > 0) {
                    if (o.edges < interval.start && (interval.start - o.edges != 1)) {
                        $panel.append('<li class="disabled"><span class="ellipse">' + o.ellipseText + '</span></li>');
                    } else if (interval.start - o.edges == 1) {
                        methods._appendItem.call(this, o.edges);
                    }
                    var end = Math.min(o.edges, interval.start);
                    for (i = end - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Generate Next link (unless option is set for at front)
            if (o.nextText && !o.nextAtFront) {
                methods._appendItem.call(this, !o.invertPageOrder ? o.currentPage + 1 : o.currentPage - 1, {text: o.nextText, classes: 'next'});
            }
        },

        _getPages: function(o) {
            var pages = Math.ceil(o.items / o.itemsOnPage);
            return pages || 1;
        },

        _getInterval: function(o) {
            return {
                start: Math.ceil(o.currentPage > o.halfDisplayed ? Math.max(Math.min(o.currentPage - o.halfDisplayed, (o.pages - o.displayedPages)), 0) : 0),
                end: Math.ceil(o.currentPage > o.halfDisplayed ? Math.min(o.currentPage + o.halfDisplayed, o.pages) : Math.min(o.displayedPages, o.pages))
            };
        },

        _appendItem: function(pageIndex, opts) {
            var self = this, options, $link, o = self.data('pagination'), $linkWrapper = $('<li></li>'), $ul = self.find('ul');

            pageIndex = pageIndex < 0 ? 0 : (pageIndex < o.pages ? pageIndex : o.pages - 1);

            options = {
                text: pageIndex + 1,
                classes: ''
            };

            if (o.labelMap.length && o.labelMap[pageIndex]) {
                options.text = o.labelMap[pageIndex];
            }

            options = $.extend(options, opts || {});

            if (pageIndex == o.currentPage || o.disabled) {
                if (o.disabled) {
                    $linkWrapper.addClass('disabled');
                } else {
                    $linkWrapper.addClass('active');
                }
                $link = $('<span class="current">' + (options.text) + '</span>');
            } else {
                $link = $('<a href="' + o.hrefTextPrefix + (pageIndex + 1) + o.hrefTextSuffix + '" class="page-link">' + (options.text) + '</a>');
                $link.click(function(event){
                    return methods._selectPage.call(self, pageIndex, event);
                });
            }

            if (options.classes) {
                $link.addClass(options.classes);
            }

            $linkWrapper.append($link);

            if ($ul.length) {
                $ul.append($linkWrapper);
            } else {
                self.append($linkWrapper);
            }
        },

        _selectPage: function(pageIndex, event) {
            var o = this.data('pagination');
            o.currentPage = pageIndex;
            if (o.selectOnClick) {
                methods._draw.call(this);
            }
            return o.onPageClick(pageIndex + 1, event);
        }

    };

    $.fn.pagination = function(method) {

        // Method calling logic
        if (methods[method] && method.charAt(0) != '_') {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.pagination');
        }

    };

})(jQuery);
```

The example of it "working" is at this link:  http://bilalakil.me/bin/simplepagination/

If you try it out, you will see my issue.  Click on a page 1, then 2, then 3.  Then click the back button.  The url will change, but the content on page and pagination button highlighted will remain the same.

How can this be fixed?  Need to fix it so that when the back button is pressed on the browser, the content actually changes, not just the url string.

P.S.  I have tried this in Firefox and Chrome.  So I don't think its a browser issue.

Comment: if u understand how it works, back button definitely won't work. the pagination is merely showing and hiding of the records in the list based on clicking on the page numbers. 1) you can listen for back button click and trigger prevPage() or do a page refresh. . . 2) everytime you trigger a nextPage() or prevPage() write to a cookie on the page number, on init of the pagination read this cookie to display accordingly

Answer (score 0):

What I see, now your current page is set as 0. That's why selected page isn't highlighted although content updated. You can try this -

```
var currentPage = $(".pagination-page").pagination().getCurrentPage();    
$(".pagination-page").pagination({
    items: numItems,
    itemsOnPage: perPage,
    cssStyle: "light-theme",
    currentPage: currentPage,
    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) { // this is where the magic happens
        // someone changed page, lets hide/show trs appropriately
        var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
        var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

        items.hide() // first hide everything, then show for the new page
             .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
    }
});
```