# Can't get simplePagination jquery plugin to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I have followed instruction of author's page:
http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/

and from this:
[How to use SimplePagination jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896076/how-to-use-simplepagination-jquery).

And i tried to implement it on my php code as below steps. I tried with firebugs but there is no error. According to the settings of js: it should displayed 5 pages and 2 results in each page. But it still displayed 10 results as normal and the pagination part only displayed this and unclickable.
[image: pagination]

1. I have included both css and js file to the header
2. My HTML which displays results from database using while loop and there is 10 results.

   ```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()
   {

    echo "<div id='item'>
           <div class='title'>$row[title]</div>
           <div class='description'>$row[description]</div>
          </div>";

   }
   ```
3. This is div which contains pagination and pagination initializer:

   ```
    <div class='pagination-page'></div>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
    var items = $("#item");
    var numItems = items.length;
    var perPage = 2;

    // only show the first 2 (or "first per_page") items initially
    items.slice(perPage).hide();

    // now setup your pagination
    // you need that .pagination-page div before/after your table
   $(".pagination-page").pagination({
   items: numItems,
   itemsOnPage: perPage,
   cssStyle: "compact-theme",
   onPageClick: function(pageNumber) { // this is where the magic happens
       // someone changed page, lets hide/show trs appropriately
       var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
       var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

       items.hide() // first hide everything, then show for the new page
            .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
         }
        });
       });
       </script>
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use div id='item'
since it produces multiple elements with the same id. 
It is very wrong, use class instead. Id must be unique. It should be sth like this...

```js
var items = $(".item");
```

```html
<div class='item' ...
```

Comment: I don't know it is a good idea to use this  pagination jquery plugins? Because my website will need to display all possible results and then this plugin only calculates number of results... If i have thousands of results retrieve from database, it will take time to load all them. Should i use php pagination instead? Because i can use Limit in sql query to display only first 0-9  results in first page, if user click 2 page, it will display 10-19 result.... what you do think? please suggest...

Comment: I would suggest php, but there may be many factors for frontend or backend solution. It might  be a topic for another stack question :)