# How to do pagination in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery. I am trying to do sorting and pagination here but a problem is it is only displaying page number not the contents on that page. I know I am doing something wrong but I am not able to figure out what is wrong.

I know the problem is onPageClick but I am not able to figure out what to write there. I already tried the examples given here but it is not helping.

I am posting my code here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/docs/js/chili/chili-1.8b.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/docs/js/docs.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $(".tablesorter").pagination({
        items: 17,
        itemsOnPage: 1,
        cssStyle: 'light-theme',
        onPageClick: function(pageNumber, event) {
                // Callback triggered when a page is clicked
                // Page number is given as an optional parameter
            },
    });
});
</script>



<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" style="width:50%">
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th><span>ID</span></th>
        <th><span>Name</span></th>
  <tr>
<tbody>
    <td>1</td>      
    <td>Jill</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>  
    <td>Bill</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>  
    <td>Chill</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>4</td>  
    <td>Chill</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>5</td>  
    <td>Chill</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>6</td>  
    <td>Chill</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>7</td>  
    <td>Chill</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>8</td>  
    <td>Chill</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>9</td>  
    <td>Chill</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>10</td> 
    <td>Chill</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>11</td> 
    <td>Chill</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>12</td> 
    <td >Chill</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td >13</td>    
    <td>Chill</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>14</td> 
    <td>Chill</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>15</td> 
    <td>Chill</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>16</td> 
    <td>Chill</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>17</td> 
    <td>Chill</td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896076/how-to-use-simplepagination-jquery

Comment: I tried this also...but no help

Comment: Can you please provide a working fiddle of your problem ?

Comment: @PietroLerro I don't have a working version...problem with me is I am able to sort the column but I am not able to show the contents of the page when clicking on the page number

Comment: Ok but .. where is the "page content" is it the other td ? the column with "chill" text into ?

Comment: Actually when we do pagination than it will display different page number...right there it is displaying correct page number as I distributed 17 rows of table in 17 different pages but on clicking a specific page it is not able to show content. Problem is in onPageClick what is should do is the problem... I am showing ID and Name in the table so for each page there is one ID and name..So Chill is the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following code in your script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/docs/js/chili/chili-1.8b.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/docs/js/docs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table") 
        .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}) 
        .tablesorterPager({container: $(".tablesorter")}); 
    }); 
</script>



<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table id="myTable" class="" style="width:50%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><span>ID</span></th>
        <th><span>Name</span></th>
      </tr>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>      
    <td>Jill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>  
    <td>Bill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>  
    <td>Chill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>  
    <td>Chill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>  
    <td>Chill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>6</td>  
    <td>Chill</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
    <td>7</td>  
    <td>Chill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>8</td>  
    <td>Chill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>9</td>  
    <td>Chill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>10</td> 
    <td>Chill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>11</td> 
    <td>Chill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>12</td> 
    <td >Chill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td >13</td>    
    <td>Chill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>14</td> 
    <td>Chill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>15</td> 
    <td>Chill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>16</td> 
    <td>Chill</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>17</td> 
    <td>Chill</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
<div id="pager" class="tablesorter" style="top: 687px; position: absolute;">
<form>
    <img src="../addons/pager/icons/first.png" class="first">
    <img src="../addons/pager/icons/prev.png" class="prev">
    <input type="text" class="pagedisplay">
    <img src="../addons/pager/icons/next.png" class="next">
    <img src="../addons/pager/icons/last.png" class="last">
    <select class="pagesize">
        <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
    </select>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[TableSort](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-trigger-sort.html)

Comment: I think you didn't understand I want to do pagination not sorting the example you posted is for sorting... I am able to do sorting but no pagination

Comment: No this is not causing any problem

Comment: i have edited your example and it is working fine now

Comment: i have separated your table and pagination div

Comment: if you need more help please refer [link](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html)

Comment: Can you please tell me that what is this for-----
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("table") 
.tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}) 
.tablesorterPager({container: $(".tablesorter")}); 
});

Comment: 1)tablesorter method initialize sorting options .2)tablesorterPager method initialize the pager

Comment: and $("table") is your content.

Comment: What if we want a search box to directly jump on the specific page in pagination...is there any code available for that?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the library is deleting the "content" part, so, even if you bind the `onPageClick` you can't show anything because it is not in the dom. You should make two `<ul>`, one for the pagination and one for the content, and link them with a data attribute.

```
<ul><li id="1"> page id 1 </li></ul>
<ul class="content"><li data-id="1"> content </li></ul>
```

then, on page click you can do

```
$('li[data-id="'+item_id+'"]').show();
```

EDIT: added example code (only changed parts)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $(".tablesorter").pagination({
        items: 17,
        itemsOnPage: 1,
        cssStyle: 'light-theme',
        onPageClick: function(pageNumber, event) {
                    // Callback triggered when a page is clicked
                    // Page number is given as an optional parameter

                    // hide all
                    hideContent();
                    //show only the one selected
                    $('li[data-id="'+pageNumber+'"]').show();

                },
    });
    function hideContent(){
        $('ul.page-contents > li').hide();
    }
    hideContent();
});
</script>


<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" style="width:50%">
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th><span>ID</span></th>
        <th><span>Name</span></th>
  <tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td>      <td>Jill</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td>  <td>Bill</td>  </tr>
  <tr><td>3</td>  <td>Chill</td></tr>
 <tr><td>4</td>  <td>Chill</td></tr>
 <tr><td>5</td>  <td>Chill</td></tr>
 <tr><td>6</td>  <td>Chill</td></tr>
 <tr><td>7</td>  <td>Chill</td></tr>
 <tr><td>8</td>  <td>Chill</td></tr>
 <tr><td>9</td>  <td>Chill</td></tr>
 <tr><td>10</td> <td>Chill</td></tr>
 <tr><td>11</td> <td>Chill</td></tr>
 <tr><td>12</td> <td >Chill</td></tr>
 <tr><td >13</td>    <td>Chill</td></tr>
 <tr><td>14</td> <td>Chill</td></tr>
 <tr><td>15</td> <td>Chill</td></tr>
 <tr><td>16</td> <td>Chill</td></tr>
 <tr><td>17</td> <td>Chill</td></tr>

</tbody>
</table>
<ul class="page-contents">
<li data-id="1"> content 1 </li>
<li data-id="2"> content 2 </li>
<li data-id="3"> content 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So for each row you are saying I have to make for pagination and other for content like ---
<ul><li id="1"> page id 3 </li></ul>
<ul class="content"><li data-id="3"> content </li></ul>
<ul><li id="1"> page id 4 </li></ul>
<ul class="content"><li data-id="4"> content </li></ul>
and so on...

Comment: You have to replicate only the `<li>` items, pairing them

Comment: Sorry... I am not understanding..and how will it help...can you please post a working example

Comment: Now clicking on the page is showing content...thanks

Comment: Excuse me @AdityaShrivastava can you please consider setting my response as accepted ? Or did you solve with the other answer from Dhaval?

Comment: yeah actually I solved with the help of answer from Dhaval