# Jquery - pagination for images inside div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I created simple image gallery and I'm looking for script or solution to make pagination for my images inside div's.

At first, it's my code.

[**CODEPEN.IO**](http://codepen.io/Luten/pen/qRpVRp)

My structure of gallery looks like this:

```
<div class="container">

 <div class="main-gallery">
  <div class="a-gallery">
   <div class="intem-gallery">
    <div class="image-gallery">
     IMAGE 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

I found [THIS](https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination) jquery pagination script but it's works on different structure, like this.

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">
  IMAGE
 </div>
</div>
```

So can this script handle it with my case or maybe someone have better solution because I need to keep eg. 4 images per site. I would like to have something that will work with my structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this [jQuery Pagination plugin](https://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/) or this one[10+ jQuery Pagination Plugins](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/). ist very easy to use. i hope it hepls

Comment: I used SimplePagination and works very good - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33413200/7376288). Thanks for the help :)